# Recommended way of wrapping a third party library c function with void* arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, c, void-pointers

I have a third party closed source c library that interfaces with hardware. The library has some api functions that accept `void *` arguments to read/write and configure some io, like so:

```
int iocall(int cmd, void * args);
int iorw(int cmd, void * buff, size_t buff_size);
```

I want to wrap these in a c++ class to  be able to inject that class, be able to mock it using gtest and introduce exceptions and get rid of all the return value checks inside the upper service classes. So far so good. Here comes my question:  What would be the best way of designing an interface for that class when it comes to the `void *` arguments?

interface.h

```
class wrap:
{
    virtual void wrap_iocall(int cmd, ??) = 0;
}
```

interface_impl.h

```
class wrap:
{
    void wrap_iocall(int cmd, ??) override
    {
        int ret{iocall(cmd, ??)};
        // do some more stuff, e.g. exceptions and so on
    }
}
```

My first take was to just overload the calls with dedicated types - but since there are a lot of them, this might be a pain to maintain and I will need to change the interface when another call is needed (e.g. other hardware call) + the library might get updates which forces me to update types.

The second thing I thought about is using `std::any` which would fit my use case but I am unsure how I would pass a pointer to the `std::any` container to the underlying c-function? I thought about pushing it into a `std::vector<std::any>` and use the `.data()` function to pass a pointer, but then I am left with a guess on the size of that container I think? And this sounds like a very bad attempt to achieve what I am looking for.

The third thing I came across was a solution using templates, but if my understanding is correct, these things cannot be virtual and hence break with my intention to mock the interface, requiring it to be virtual. So I think this might not work either.

The last thing I can currently think of is sticking to just `void *` in the wrapping function and have the upper service layer handle the type casts, e.g. allocate the struct for the specific device call and pass the pointer to the `void *` argument of the wrapper. This is by far my least favorite option.

I want to stick to the principle of type safe function arguments but I am not sure of how to proceed from here. Any help/feedback is appreciated!

Comment: What does the documentation say about the `args` argument? And I really don't see any need to wrap these calls in a class, if they're just going to call the actual functions anyway. Passing pointers to a function expecting `void*` is just fine, as long as the pointers are pointing to data that the function expects.

Comment: If the data passed depends on the `cmd`, then it might make make sense to wrap the function using *different* functions (could be in a namespace, could be `static` member functions of a class that can't be instantiated), passing only the suitable argument with an explicit type (`int`, `struct` or other). The function then calls the actual `iocall` function with the correct `cmd` and the suitable pointer. It also makes it easier to name your functions semantically better.

Comment: How many possible values for `cmd` are we talking about? My first idea would be to provide one read and one write function per value of `cmd`, and use the correct types there as arguments.

Comment: Similarly with `iorw`, you could use functions like `write_int` which writes a single `int` value, or `write_int_n` which writes multiple `int` values (as an array), etc. With corresponding read functions of course.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply guys. There are around 48 structs for dedicated iocalls with different layouts, that need to be passed to the ```void *``` arg with the accompanying cmd . Thats pretty much it. Your point is absolutly valid - the only thing I want to wrap this is so I can mock the stuff and easily test it using dependency injection. So you would advise me to write dedicated functions depending on the cmd? Ok - sounds good to me :)

Comment: Automate it! Create a simple configuration file that maps a `cmd` to a structure. Then create a simple script that creates the C++ code that contains the function definitions that takes the correct structure, and calls the `iocall` with the right `cmd`. Could use simple plain overloading (so you have `inline int iocall(structure_one* arg) { return iocall(CMD_FOR_STRUCT_ONE, arg); }` and so on).

Comment: Thank you so much! Will do this! Cheers!

Comment: You could create a `protected` function with basically the same signature as the C function for mocking purposes and use template functions for the typesafety, you could use `constexpr` objects that contain type info, e.g. `template<class ArgType>struct Command { int m_commandValue; using value_type = ArgType; int operator()(wrap& w, value_type  value) const { return w.iocall(m_commandValue, &value); } }; constexpr Command<int> SomeIntCommand { 42 }; class wrap { ... template<class Command> void WarpCall(Command const& cmd, typename Command::value_type v) { auto res = cmd(*this, v); } };`

Comment: ^^^This allows you to add a new command in a single line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions and comments. I have chosen to implement the calls as seperate functions as suggested.Since they do depend on the `cmd` value, I used that field for dedicated naming of the functions + the appropriate struct. I wrote a small python script to automate the code creation.

Again, thank you all for the fast response!

Cheers!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your needs correctly. However, it also seems that you yourself are not sure what you need :)

So I present a solution based on templates and parameters packs. I hope this example can gives you an idea of what can be done.

```
#include <iostream>

// My mockups of production and test funcions
int iocall(int cmd, ...){
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, cmd);
    std::cout << "iocall cmd=" << cmd;
    for(int x = 0; x < cmd; ++x) 
        std::cout << " " << va_arg(vl, void*);
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
};

int iotest(int cmd, ...){
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, cmd);
    std::cout << "testcall cmd=" << cmd;
    for(int x = 0; x < cmd; ++x)
        std::cout << " " << va_arg(vl, void*);
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
};

// Wrappers
struct do_iocall {
    template <typename... Args>
    int operator()(int cmd, Args... args) 
        { return iocall(cmd, static_cast<void*>(args)...); }
};

struct do_testcall {
    template <typename... Args>
    int operator()(int cmd, Args... args) 
        { return iotest(cmd, static_cast<void*>(args)...); }
};

// Pseudo-main class of application
template <class T>
class BigEngine {
    T wrapper;
public:
    int RunEverything(){
        struct One {} one;
        struct Two {} two;

        wrapper(1, &one);
        wrapper(2, &one, &two);
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Production run
    BigEngine<do_iocall> prod;
    prod.RunEverything();

    // Test run
    BigEngine<do_testcall> test;
    test.RunEverything();
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eqbz8s6oe